# Black Space Top and Left of Web Page

Tags: jquery, html, css

There is a mysterious white/blank space to the top and left of my website, at www.frameaface.com . When I use Chrome Developer Tools, there doesn't appear to be css information that corresponds to that space, which leads me to believe it is a jquery issue.  Can you guide me to either the css/html reason this is happening on the site or how I can test for a jquery issue?

Thanks.

Comment: your body has a margin top and left of 18 px remove that and it should work fine, check your site.css or

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove style `margin-left` and `margin-top` in your index on line 812, set `html,body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }`

Answer (score 0):

Set the body margin to 0 like this:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

You currently have an 18px margin on your body which is why you see the black space.

Answer (score 0):

***Update*** The 18px margin-top and margin-left were in a  file.  The css statement in this file (the contact/mail submission) was causing the border in the main index.php document.

I have not specifically had to trace a css issue back to a  before, now I know! Thanks for all replies.